# Hot swap/plug components in clojure?

Tags: clojure, osgi

I'm using OSGi for some time and I **really** like the ability to swap/replace components while my application is running. I simply have to build my module and push it to the OSGi container.

Is there a similar concept/framework for clojure?

I know about leiningen's dependency management which really helps modularity but I know of no built-in way to hot swap code.

Comment: Clojure has high-order functions and immutability.  You can "hot-swap" any time you like.  A Google Search for [Clojure Hot Swap](https://www.google.com/search?q=clojure%20hot%20swap) yielded [this](http://travis-whitton.blogspot.com/2009/09/hot-code-swapping-with-clojure.html) as the first search result.

Answer (score 2):

The notion of "hot swapping" doesn't really make sense in Clojure, at least not as something different from normal. It's always possible to change things by re-evaluating the code that you want to change.

It's worth having a look at pomegranate which allows you to dynamically add new dependencies.